# 痛くなったり grammar?

Tags: grammar, parsing

I'm having trouble understanding 痛{いた}くなったり (itakunattari). Appears to be itakunai + the "tari" adverb thing. But then why is it 痛{いた}くなったり and not 痛{いた}くなたり

Comment: it actually comes from「痛くなる」rather than「痛くない」if that helps

Comment: If JansthcirlU's comment doesn't solve your problem then some more context will be needed.

Answer (score 2):

As a comment says, 痛くなる has two parts - 痛い + なる, meaning something becomes a pain.
なる + たり is なったり, since it's too mouthful to say なたり, just like the past tense for なる is なった not なた

Answer (score 1):

This "たり” grammar, is basically `the past tense of the word + たり`

> 痛くなる -> 痛くなった -> 痛くなったり

> 痛くない -> 痛くなかった -> 痛くなかったり

Comment: I find your answer a bit confusing. Do you mean that there is an etymological connection between the past tense of なる and its たり-form, or do you just mean that they just happen to have a similar form? Also, it would be good if you specified that なる is the actual verb here, not 痛くなる.